# Speed up video output to the screen, or reduce the rendering load on the CPU

Tags: wpf, visual-c++, c++-cli, libvlc

At the moment the video is displayed on the screen of WPF control without problems, except for the high load on the CPU. The output of the video is made by copying pixels from the unmanaged code to `WritableBitmap`, decoding which is engaged LIBVLC. Is it possible to reduce the CPU load by the example of hardware acceleration? I do not understand how it is possible to do so, and is it possible at all.

In this image, you can see the CPU load while the video is on the screen:

[image]

The video output is made by the following code:

```
void WpfMediaPlayer::OnRender(DrawingContext ^ drawingContext)
{
    FrameworkElement^ parent = (FrameworkElement^)VisualTreeHelper::GetParent(this);
    if (!parent)
        return;

    Matrix matrix = ((Transform^)TransformToVisual(parent))->Value;
    drawingContext->DrawRectangle(System::Windows::Media::Brushes::Black,
        gcnew System::Windows::Media::Pen(),
        Rect(System::Windows::Point(0 - matrix.OffsetX, 0 - matrix.OffsetY), System::Windows::Size(RenderSize.Width + matrix.OffsetX * 2, RenderSize.Height + matrix.OffsetY * 2)));
    bmWrite->WritePixels(Int32Rect(0, 0, bmWrite->PixelWidth, bmWrite->PixelHeight), IntPtr(ptr_image_), size_img_ptr, (width * bmWrite->Format.BitsPerPixel) / 8);
    drawingContext->DrawImage(bmWrite, Rect(System::Windows::Point(), RenderSize));
}
```

Comment: Kudos for using WPF with C++, take a look at https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet

Comment: @Aybe: don't need it

Comment: There is a bunch of C code in this repository -> you can always see how they did it and do the same on your project.

Comment: @Aybe: These guys use a picture on the disc, followed by reading, which affects performance. It looks funny. =)

Comment: Really ? The only other thing I can think of then is something like `InteropBitmap`, you blit onto it and let WPF pull the pixels, but you need an `Image` control for that.

Comment: You need special accelerated API, DirectX (Direct2D or Direct3D) or OpenGL